# Realm db wrapper using GCD

Tags: ios, database, swift, grand-central-dispatch, realm

I have implemented wrapper (manager) around `Realm` for simplifying its usage. I've made udpate and fetch methods to update and get data from database. All writes and reads are made on custom `GCD` async queue.

I have already acknowledged that `Realm` objects are not thread safe.

However I would like to have local (in cache) instances of fetched objects on main thread cos I don't want to read data from `Realm` db for every single access.

Like you probably know this wouldn't work as it gives me this pesky `accessed from incorrect thread` error.

What is the appropriate solution of having local copy of objects on main thread and still be able to update this objects in db?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy built-in to pull-back Realm objects into memory. (This is a non-trivial task for objects with relations as those could be cyclic.)

Currently, the easiest way is to pass instead primary keys / indexes around and rely on those to independently access the objects via the thread-specific Realm.

Note that there is the 3rd-party component [RBQSafeRealmObject](https://github.com/Roobiq/RBQSafeRealmObject), which implements this strategy generically and hides away the instantiation of the correct Realm and object retrieval via primary key.

Comment: Hope Realm team will dig into this issue soon. Until than this kind of workarounds should be applied. Thanks!